# how to enforce positive constraints in cvx?

Tags: matlab, cvxpy, cvx

I have a simple CVX program, where two variables are:

```
variable A(n, n)
variable D(n, N)
```

I learned from here:

https://mycourses.aalto.fi/pluginfile.php/1612433/mod_resource/content/1/lec06.pdf

that I think adding the constraints A >= 0 (and even possibly D >= 0) will not enforce A to be all of positive values, but rather for A to be a positive definite.

How do I enforce instead for all elements of A to be positive (and similar for D)?

I am using Matlab.

Comment: Apologies. after further inspection, I learned that A >= 0 *is* enforcing element-wise positivity.

Comment: It depends if you are in SDP mode or not.